# Assigning undefined to a property in constructor

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization

I read that you'd better have a fixed structure of an object, just having to change properties values, not remove/add properties themselves so that JavaScript engine optimizes it better, like this:

```
var MyClass = function(){
    this.prop = undefined;
}    
var a = new MyClass();
```

I find this quite messy and one of shady JavaScript hacks, although can use it if it really boosts the run of the app.

Though, I am a bit skeptical about this trick in a frontend application, even if it's a complex one consisting of 100s of classes and components.

So, the question is, does it in practice make sense to assign properties initial values in constructors? Or is it more a hypothetical performance optimization which can be hardly noticed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does it in practice make sense to assign properties initial values in constructors?

Yes, absolutely. It does improve clarity, both to the optimising compiler and the human reader, which is especially important in larger code bases.

However, that you are trying to construct objects without initialised properties might hint at a more general design flaw. When you don't even know reasonable initial values, maybe you should not instantiate anything until you know them.